# Ruby Puppet Regex string matching

Tags: regex, case, puppet

I'm somewhat new to ruby and have done a ton of google searching but just can't seem to figure out how to match this particular pattern.  I have used [rubular.com](http://rubular.com) and can't seem to find a simple way to match.  Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have several types of hosts, they take this form:

Sample hostgroups

```
host-brd0000.localdomain
host-cat0000.localdomain
host-dog0000.localdomain
host-bug0000.localdomain
```

Next I have a case statement, I want to keep out the bugs (who doesn't right?).  I want to do something like this to match the series of characters.  However, it starts matching at host-b, host-c, host-d, and matches only a single character as if I did a `[brdcatdog]`.

```
case $hostgroups {  #variable takes the host string up to where the numbers begin
# animals to keep
             /host-[["brd"],["cat"],["dog"]]/: {
             file {"/usr/bin/petstore-friends.sh":
                owner   => petstore,
                group   => petstore,
                mode    => 755,
                source  => "puppet:///modules/petstore-friends.sh.$hostgroups",
             }
}
```

I could do something like `[bcd][rao][dtg]` but it's not very clean looking and will match nonsense like "bad""cot""dat""crt" which I don't want.

Is there a slick way to use `\A` and `[]` that I'm missing?

Thanks for your help.

-wootini

Answer (score 2):

How about using negative lookahead?

```
host-(?!bug).*
```

Here is the [RUBULAR permalink](http://rubular.com/r/SzbtVou1aK) matching everything except those **pesky bugs!**

Comment: This is helpful and appreciate it for some other cases, but not exactly what I need for this case as rats and spiders could be introduced next!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
host-(brd|cat|dog)
```

(Following gtgaxiola's example, here's the [Rubular permalink](http://rubular.com/r/79WkJdMfUH))